# Is it possible to recover field values from the browser form cache across reloads for generated INPUTs?

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, google-chrome

When building custom widgets it's usually nice to always keep your widget-state inside in the value attribute of actual browser inputs as most browsers will preserve those values across reloads or when hitting 'back'. This usually works well.

However, any sort of "growing" custom-widgets that generate new inputs during use are not handled similarly. I was hoping I could save the "new" widget count in a hidden field and then on domReady simply generate the missing input fields and assign them their original names and IDs but this doesn't seem to work, browsers don't seem to want to do anything with generated content.

Overall this is probably sensible enough, but is there maybe a way to interact with this form cache mechanism directly? One possible work-around would be to store not only the new item count in a hidden field but some sort of serialization of the full content of the new widgets.  Should work but it's a fair bit of additional effort :/

Barring all this is there any good reference available that describes this caching mechanism? I don't suppose it's part of a spec? (seems quite likely it's just incidentally similar behaviour provided by all major browser vendors)